# Google LoginButton not working in api 23

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

Just upgraded my project to the newest api and my google login button does not work anymore. I would post my code but I figured that it must be a known bug after with permissions or something.

Symptom: Onclick, it shows local accounts. Disappears after clicking one and displays Log In.

Also, I was never able to set it up to automatically use accounts stored on the phone. I was always forced to enter information into the webview every single time I logged in/registered.

Let me know what you think about the first issue and if you can point me to the documentation for automatically using local accounts that would be great.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: thank you for that comment, I really appreciate it. I will likely use that doc to make my google login more slick. That being said I did specifically ask why the webview was displayed on a project with lillipop target and not displayed on a project with marshmellow target. edit: i take it back that was a shit post with no context.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems google-signin is not working properly with Android versions >=5. You can leave empty the GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(), but in this case you will get only the email.

Comment: I never had auto sign in working.  Im going to rewrite my code and I'll report back when I fix it.